# Date comparison to restrict user to select until current date

Tags: android, datetimepicker

I have a DatePickerDialog in my app and I want the date selected by the user to be restricted until the current date. I am comparing the date selected from the DatePickerDialog with the newDate() and if the selected date is before, I am throwing an error. Please find the code as follows.

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                          int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        calendar.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
                        String visitDate = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
                        try {
                            Date appointDate = dateFormat.parse(visitDate);
                            Date currentDate = new Date();
                            if(appointDate.before(currentDate)){
                                appointmentDateInputLayout.setError("Date selected is not within range!");
                            }else{
                                appointmentDateEditText.setText(visitDate);
                                appointmentDateInputLayout.setError(null);
                            }
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        appointmentDateEditText.setText(visitDate);
                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
        datePickerDialog.show();
```

But when I do this, I am getting an error for selecting today's date also. I want the user to allow the current date. What am I missing here?

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look, the

```
    Date currentDate = new Date() ;
```

allocates the date object at the time it was instantiated in the degree of Milliseconds so alternating the allocation and putting date object at the first of the code would give the very early time so the time that you take to choose visitdate would be eventually greater (after) so the number of Milliseconds in the currentDate will be less than number of Milliseconds in the Picked new Date

Answer (score 0):

Try to compare with calendar  getTime()  method instead of current  date.:

```
 If(appointDate.before(calendar.getTime())
```

Comment: Ok then change the format of the date so that it contains the minuets and seconds as well:    
                                                                                                             
       String currentDate = new 
       SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd 
       HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());